# Convert array result into integer for calculating

Tags: php

I have a little problem with an array.
I have an array which looks like this:

```
Array
(

    [start] => Array
        (
            [0] => 15168
        )

    [ende] => Array
        (
            [0] => 43
        )

    [string] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1050
        )

)
```

The number I need is 1050. So I get it like this:

```
$number = $tabelle['string'][0];
```

Now my problem is that I can't use it in calculations. I already tried to convert it into an integer with the following line:

```
$number = intval($tabelle['string'][0]);
```

But this doesn't work. I always get 0 for $number. How to do it properly? I already searched on Google for about 2 hours.

Best regards

My whole script:

```
 <?php

class data_pars {

    var $datei;
    var $read_laenge = 2000;
    var $result;


    function set_datei($datei) {

        $this->datei = $datei;
    }

    function read($start,$ende) {

        $file = @fopen ($this->datei,"r");

        while (!feof($file)) {

            $inhalt .= fgets($file,$this->read_laenge);
        }

        if(!$start) $start = 0;
        if(!$ende) $ende = strlen($inhalt);

        if($ende > strlen($inhalt)) $ende = strlen($inhalt);

        $this->result = substr($inhalt,$start,$ende);

    }

    function get_result() {

        return $this->result;
    }

    function get_in_out($in,$out,$in_out) {

    $anzahl_ende = strlen($out);
    $anzahl_start = strlen($in);
    $start = 0; 
    $anzahl = substr_count($this->result, $in);
    $count = 0;

    if(!$in_out) {

        $ad_start = $anzahl_start;
        $ad_ende = $anzahl_ende;
    }

    while($count < $anzahl) {

        $ar_start = strpos($this->result, $in, $start);
        $ar_ende = strpos($this->result, $out, $ar_start + $anzahl_start);
        $ar_string = substr($this->result,$ar_start + $ad_start, $ar_ende - $ar_start + $anzahl_ende - $ad_ende - $ad_start);

        $output[start][] = $ar_start;
        $output[ende][] = $ar_ende - $ar_start + $anzahl_ende;
        $output[string][] = trim($ar_string);

        $start = $ar_start + $anzahl_start;

        $count++;

    }    


    return $output;

    }    


}



$data = new data_pars();

$data->set_datei('http://www.elitepvpers.com/theblackmarket/profile/6005376');
$data->read('0','20000');

$tabelle = $data->get_in_out('<td>elite*gold:</td>','</td>',false);
$number = intval($tabelle['string'][0]);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($tabelle);
echo '</pre>';
echo $number;
?>
```

So I always get 0 for $number instead of 1050;

Comment: Works fine for me! Please show us the code where you want to use this number

Comment: I suspect there is more code involved.

Comment: I added the whole code. Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did 2 main errors:

1. You have to initialize `$inhalt` before your while loop like this:

```
$inhalt = "";
while (!feof($file)) {
    $inhalt .= fgets($file,$this->read_laenge);
}
```

2. You forgot to put quotes around the indexes:

```
$output["start"][] = $ar_start;
$output["ende"][] = $ar_ende - $ar_start + $anzahl_ende;
$output["string"][] = trim($ar_string);
```

And now why did your `intval()` failed? Because if you right click and show source you will see in the array the value is:

```
<td>1050
```

So this can't convert to a `int`! And the `<td>` you don't see, because it's a html tag

Now you can easy extract only the number with this lines:

```
$tabelle["string"]["0"] = filter_var($tabelle["string"]["0"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
echo $number = intval($tabelle["string"]["0"]);
```

Output:

```
1050
```

Comment: Whoops, I forgot that I had a <td> before it. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: @TheRealNoXx This can happen to everybody, especially when it's a html tag which you only see in the source code

Comment: Yeah you're right. I like the fact that you also live in Switzerland.

Comment: @TheRealNoXx BTW: Since you're new here  you can take a tour here: http://stackoverflow.com/tour And see how this site works! (Do you come from Switzerland too?)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your code and logic correctly.
try replace:

```
$output[start][] = $ar_start;
        $output[ende][] = $ar_ende - $ar_start + $anzahl_ende;
        $output[string][] = trim($ar_string);
```

to this:
$

```
output['start'][] = intval($ar_start);
        $output['ende'][] =intval( $ar_ende - $ar_start + $anzahl_ende);
        $output['string'][] = intval(trim($ar_string));
```